# Laravel, aumentar os campos padrão da autenticação User, já pronta no laravel via composer

Tags: php, laravel, autenticação

Olá queria aumentar o número de campos do formulário de autenticação para inserir novos campos.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

Eu queria colocar mais campos para inserir via formulário, tanto a validação como no insert.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('senha');
        $table->string('endereco');
        $table->string('cidade');
        $table->string('telefone');
        $table->string('razao_social');
        $table->string('cnpj')->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a me informar aonde fica estes campos?

Comment: Ai tem um porém, antes ou depois de rodar o primeiro migration de `users` tem diferenças nos comandos!

Comment: relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165058/54880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para adicionar campos extras no usuário padrão do laravel, faça as seguintes alterações:

database/migrations/xxxx_xx_xx_xxxxxx_create_users_table.php

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...

    $table->string('phone')->nullable();

    ...
}
```

Agora, atualize seu modelo para acompanhar as mudanças da migration, adicione dentro da propriedade fillable os novos atributos.:

app\User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    protected $fillable = [
        'phone',
    ];

    ...
}
```

Agora você deve alterar o validador dentro do `controller` padrão de autenticação, vamos adicionar uma validação simples para a nova propriedade dentro do método `validator`. Veja como ficou:

app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    ...

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone' => 'string|min:8|max:13',
    ]);

    ...
}
```

Adicione também a propriedade dentro do método `create` no mesmo arquivo:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    ...

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
    ]);

    ...
}
```

Por último, você deve adicionar o novo campo dentro do seu código html da forma que desejar, mas, com o mesmo nome que você adicionou no método `create` do `controller`. Os formulários padrões de login e registro, normalmente se localizam em `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` e `resources/views/auth/register.blade.php`.

O melhor a se fazer, é ler a página de autenticação na [documentação oficial do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication), é bem simples e detalhado.