# Criar/Modificar tabela sem excluir dados Laravel Migrate

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5, artisan

Eu estou com uma dúvida sobre o laravel com relação as Migrates. Estou usando o Laravel 5.1 com banco de dados SQLite.

Quando eu rodo o comando `php artisan migrate` ou php `artisan migrate:refresh`, geralmente para acrescentar novas tabelas ou inserir novos campos a tabelas já existentes, os dados que existiam anteriormente se perdem.

Imagina o cenário onde o sistema já em produção com diversos dados cadastrados, precisa de um novo campo em uma determinada tabela. Terei então que rodar o `php artisan migrate` e os dados serão perdidos.

Minha pergunta é: Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa atualização do banco de dados sem excluir os dados das tabelas?

Comment: Você tem as `migrations` que por exemplo adiciona campos em um tabela existente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando se cria um [**migrations**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations) pelo comando:

```
php artisan make:migrations create_cars
```

É criado um arquivo em branco com dois métodos: `up()` e `down()`, e dentro deles são escritos o que é para ser feito, ***exemplo***:

- [Cria tabela](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-tables)
- [Renomear ou Excluir tabela](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)
- [Criar colunas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-columns)
- [Colunas modificadas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#column-modifiers)
- [Modificar colunas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns)
- [Excluir colunas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#dropping-columns)
- [Criar indices](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-indexes)
- [Excluir indices](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#dropping-indexes)
- [Foreign Key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

---

> Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa atualização do banco de dados sem excluir os dados das tabelas?

Criando um [**migrations**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations) `create_cars` e dentro dos seus metodos:

```
class create_cars extends Migration
{    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('model', 100);
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('cars');
    }
}
```

rode o comando `php artisan migrate` e é criado a tabela com essas configurações e campos.

> Logo após deseja uma mudança na estrutura dessa tabela que é a criação de um campo `active`, mas, que os dados existente não sejam perdidos.

Crie um novo [**migrations**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations) com o comando `php artisan make:migrations cars_add_active` e em vez de `Schema::create` que é para criar a tabela, coloque `Schema::table` que permite alteração na estrutura dessa tabela, que pode ser adicionar campos, índices, relacionamentos **e/ou** excluir também. No caso exemplo é adicionado um campo na tabela com o nome de `active`, do tipo `TINYINT(4)` com o valor padrão **1** e pode receber valores `null`.

```
class cars_add_active extends Migration
{    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('cars', function($table){
            $table->tinyInteger('active')
                ->default(1)
                ->nullable();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Lembrando que os dados existente nunca serão excluídos como foi explicado no exemplo.

Existe aqui todas as [configurações para colunas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns) e a explicação de como proceder.

***Observação:*** *não esqueça de instalar o pacote* `composer require` [doctrine/dbal](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal)

**Referencias:**

- [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations)
- [creating-tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-tables)
- [renaming-and-dropping-tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)
- [Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns)